# How to apply a factor analysis applying spearman correlation to the principal() in R?

Tags: r, correlation

To test it can be used the mtcars which have non-parametric distribution.
I am developing a factor analysis. My data is non-parametric in nature. Therefore, according to the literature, it is recommended to apply the Spearman test. I'm using fuction:

```
root.fa2 <- principal(dt, 
                  nfactors = 3, 
                  rotate = 'varimax',
                  scores=T, 
                  residuals =T,
                  oblique.scores=T,
                  method="regression",
                  spearman="cor",
                  use = "all.obs")
```

By default, she uses the option **cor = "cor"** applying the Person test. However, this is indicated for parametric data.
The **spearman = "cor"** option is valid for the function. However, this error is returning ->
Error in stats::varimax(loadings, ...) : unused argument (spearman = "cor"). This only happens when I define a **nfactors** > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not a clear as it might be here, but looking at the documentation for `MixedCor` the following works and gives you your scores:

```
root.fa2 <- principal(mtcars, nfactors = 3, 
        rotate = 'varimax', scores=TRUE, residuals=TRUE, oblique.scores=TRUE,
        method="regression", use = "all.obs", cor="spearman")
```

Note. It is good practice to spell out `TRUE` and `FALSE` since they are reserved words. `T` and `F` will usually work, but they are not reserved so that you can accidentally assign `T` or `F` to a value in some other part of your code.

Comment: If it is the one in package psych? Yes.
The option "spearman" is available in the function code, should it work?
Follows part of the code function preparing for the spearman:
  switch(cor, cor = {
    if (!is.null(weight)) {r <- cor.wt(r, w = weight)$r }
    else {r <- cor(r, use = use)}, 
    ...,
    spearman = {r <- cor(r, use = use, method = "spearman")}, 
    kendall = {r <- cor(r, use = use, method = "kendall"),...
  }
Hi, a part works. However, root.fa2 $ scores = NULL returns. A 32x3 matrix was to be returned. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Not yet. It isn't generating the root.fa2 $ scores output. Applying the commented example is returning NULL. The 32x3 matrix must be returned.

Comment: **Not** the commented suggestion, the proposed answer above. When I run that code, I get a 32 x 3 matrix for root.fa2$scores.